# Excel: Run A Macro On Cell Click

Tags: excel, cell, vba

I am using the following code to insert todays date into a cell when a user clicks onto another cell in that row.

At the moment the code is set out like so; if a user clicks cell AQ8 then insert date into cell AS8.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Address = "$AQ$8" Then
       Range("AS8").Value = DATE
    End If
End Sub
```

however, now i want to change this code slightly so that when a user changes any AQ cell in either row then the subsequent AS cell has the date inserted into the appropriate cell for that row. So if cell AQ9 is clicked then AS9 shows todays date and when they click AQ10 then AS10 shows todays date and so on. Would this be written as a target row function? and if so how would i write something like this? Can someone please show me how i could get this to do what i need, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to refer to columns by number, i.e. you want to use "AQ" instead of 43, then the following should work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = Range("AQ1").Column Then
    Range("AS" & Target.Row).Value = Date
  End If
End Sub
```

The reference to row 1 in `AQ1` is a dummy, since the code just selects the `.Column` of that range.

I'm using `Worksheet_Change` because you said *"when a user **changes** any AQ cell"*. If you only want this to happen when a user ***clicks*** on a cell, then you can keep using the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event.

Comment: Hi this doesnt seem to be working for me, i am clicking on the cell AQ and nothing is being inserted into the AS cell

Comment: @markjay: As I said in my answer, in your question you specified that you want this to happen when a user ***changes*** any AQ cell. If you want this to happen when a user only ***selects*** any AQ cell, then you need to replace `Worksheet_Change` with `Worksheet_SelectionChange`. Quoting from your question: *"however, now i want to change this code slightly so that when a user **changes** any AQ cell in either row then the subsequent AS cell has the date inserted into the appropriate cell for that row."*

Answer (score 0):

Update like that:

```
If Target.Column = 43 Then
   Range("AS" & Target.Row).Value = Date
End If
```

every rows in column AQ = 43 are updated with the date.

Comment: thanks but would this not update the cell no matter which cell was clicked on in that row? i only want cell AS to have the date inserted if cell AQ from each row is clicked

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. The code update the columns AS in base of the row of AQ with the today data...