# How to trigger macros when clicking on a specific cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to trigger two independent macros each based on different cells.  To be specific, I want to trigger the Orange macro when cell E8 is clicked. And the Factiva macro when cell E9 is clicked. This is the code I came up with so far,,,, but does not work... The two macros are related to showing a graph(normal bar graph) !

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E9")) Is Nothing Then
            Call Factiva
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E8")) Is Nothing Then
            Call Orange
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Sub Factiva()
'
' Factiva Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("factiva")).Visible = msoFalse
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("factiva")).Visible = msoTrue
    Application.CommandBars("Selection").Visible = False
End Sub

Sub Orange()
'
' Orange Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Orange Business")).Visible = msoFalse
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Orange Business")).Visible = msoTrue
    Application.CommandBars("Selection").Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: [This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203227/excel-run-a-macro-on-cell-click)

Comment: In my case, I am trying to run more than one macro :) And I am confused how to write the code... Thanks for the reference though!

Comment: You may not use `Worksheet_SelectionChange` twice. Just put your two `If not...` blocks in one Sub and you will be fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two procedures with the same name in the same module, or two handlers for the same worksheet event in a `Worksheet` module. `Option Explicit` isn't valid anywhere else than in a module's *declarations* section, at the very top (you can't have it between procedures).

You need the `SelectionChange` handler to determine which cell is selected, and decide which macro it wants to invoke accordingly.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub 'bail out immediately instead of nesting

    Select Case True
        Case Not Intersect(Target, Range("E9")) Is Nothing
            Factiva 'note: Call keyword is redundant

        Case Not Intersect(Target, Range("E8")) Is Nothing
            Orange 'note: Call keyword is redundant

        'Case ...

    End Select
End Sub
```

Note that if that is the only code that needs to invoke the `Factiva` and `Orange` procedures, then they can both be made `Private`. Also, consider renaming your procedures using meaningful names that start with a verb, e.g. `ShowFactivaShape`, or `ShowOrangeBusinessShape`.

In fact, you could parameterize the code and remove one of the two:

```
Private Sub ShowShape(ByVal shapeName As String)
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(shapeName).Visible = msoTrue
    Application.CommandBars("Selection").Visible = False
End Sub
```

Note that there shouldn't be a need to set visibility to `msoFalse` before you set it to `msoTrue`, and the `Shapes.Range(Array(...))` is superfluous, since you're only interested in a single named `Shape`.

The `SelectionChange` handler would then look like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub 'bail out immediately instead of nesting

    Select Case True
        Case Not Intersect(Target, Range("E9")) Is Nothing
            ShowShape "Factiva"

        Case Not Intersect(Target, Range("E8")) Is Nothing
            ShowShape "Orange Business"

        'Case ...

    End Select
End Sub
```

Consider making a similar `HideShape` procedure if you need to hide "Orange Business" when "Factiva" is shown, and vice-versa - or better, consider adding a `Optional ByVal isVisible As Boolean = True` parameter to `ShowShape`, and then you can use the same procedure for both purposes:

```
Private Sub ShowShape(ByVal shapeName As String, Optional ByVal isVisible As Boolean = True)
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(shapeName).Visible = IIf(isVisible, msoTrue, msoFalse)
    Application.CommandBars("Selection").Visible = False
End Sub
```

That way you can easily show/hide shapes as needed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub 'bail out immediately instead of nesting

    Select Case True
        Case Not Intersect(Target, Range("E9")) Is Nothing
            ShowShape "Factiva"
            ShowShape "Orange Business", isVisible:=False

        Case Not Intersect(Target, Range("E8")) Is Nothing
            ShowShape "Orange Business"
            ShowShape "Factiva", isVisible:=False

        'Case ...

    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: out of curiosity, what if there are 6 shapes. So when one is shown, the rest must be hidden,,, In this case, how would the coding change? Thanks!

Comment: @MooChangPark I saw that one coming, ...see the last two snippets in the post.

Comment: Like the last snippet, should I add a line like ```ShowShape "Orange Business", isVisible:=False``` for every other shapes that must be hidden?

Comment: Say, when Shape Factiva is shown, Orange, Shape 1, shape 2, shape 3 must be hidden...

Comment: @MooChangPark yes, as shown above. Call the `ShowShape` procedure with `isVisible:=False` for each shape you want to hide.