# In VBA, how do I open a template in notepad that is populated with cell values?

Tags: excel, vba, notepad

I am new to VBA and I am trying to create a Macro that will allow me to click on a specific cell on excel and it will open up a notepad template and populate the template with the cell data. Is this possible?

Comment: Have a look at the answers to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42224880 - there are several methods there to achieve your requirement.

Comment: You might find some help here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203227/excel-run-a-macro-on-cell-click